# bootstrap form fields not extending to the full length

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page using bootstrap that has a form. What do I need to do for the fields on the form to extend all the way to the end of the empty space?

```
   <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="Name">Name</label>
       <input class="form-control col-md-8" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" />
   </div>
```

[image]

This is the goal:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `col-*` on the same element as `form-control`. Nest the `input.form-control` within a `div.col-*` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="Name">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The html should be as follows, then only the input element will take 100% of the width and there won't be empty space:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="Name">Name</label>
   <div class="col-md-8">
       <input class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" />
   </div>
</div>
```

[Refer horizontal form css using twitter bootstrap.](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)

Answer (score 1):

Delete both `col-md-*` classes from `<label>` and `<input>` elements.

Comment: when I delete the col-md-... I get the label on top of the input box. the input box still does not extend to the end.

Comment: Add to ```form-group```'s parent the ```form-horizontal``` class and check to see if it has the ```width``` or ```max-width``` property with a value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use the grid view the parent element needs to have a "row" class. This means you keep the col-md-*  classes.nif you want to use the form CSS then use what you have in the parent and remove the col-md-* classes